# Print without newline in command line mode

Tags: output, command-line

Does Mathematica provide any way to print text to the terminal *without a newline at the end* when running in command line mode?  There are many workarounds with the notebook interface, but this question is specifically about the command line.

I would like to use this for more detailed progress monitoring on a headless machine.  The only solution I could think of so far is using LibraryLink to do the printing, which isn't that bad actually as I do already have a LibraryLink component in this program.

To sum up, I want a `print` function so that

```
Do[Pause[1]; print["."], {5}]
```

produces

```
.....
```

in a terminal session and the dots appear gradually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems my question was premature.  This can be done by writing to `stdout` using [`WriteString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WriteString.html).

Notice that `stdout` is open as a stream:

```
In[13]:= Streams[]                                                              
Out[13]= {OutputStream[stdout, 1], OutputStream[stderr, 2]}
```

We can simply use

```
Do[WriteString[OutputStream["stdout",1] ,"."], {5}]
```

This works on OS X and Linux. I haven't tried on Windows.

Comment: Works on Windows too.